# IE6 + silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, internet-explorer-6

I have not much experience with silverlight but would like to know whether I6 works with silverlight 4. According to the compatibility matrix [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight) it does. Can you experts please confirm this? Thanks!

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience IE6 should work fine with silverlight 4.

Comment: I'm kinda surprised nobody else responded to this question yet.